# Problem in .bashrc

Tags: bashrc, paths, .profile

I try to edit .bashrc to view the C-compilers that I installed before.
But after opening the new terminal I am stuck with strange error.

I am unable to `ls` the files/directories and nothing works. It hangs with the following error message on command line:

```
vi .bashrc
Command `vi` is available in /usr/bin/vi
The command could not be located because /usr/bin is not included in the PATH environment variable.
vi: command not found
```

Can anyone please assist me ?

Comment: The likely error was in attempting to change the **path** variable (with a syntax error), from within **.bashrc**. Instead, I suggest using **.profile**, and base your effort on the existing content.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still logged in, or can login to the graphical session without problems, then you can copy the file `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to your home directory (be aware that hidden files are not shown by default in the file manager.

As an alternative, press F2 then launch the command

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/your-username
```

If these methods do not work, then you have to follow the method shown by @gertvdijk.

Comment: +1. Sounds like a quicker solution to try first.

Comment: I found the solution by editing the .bashrc by following the full path of editor    /usr/bin/gedit /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bashrc Thanks to all, specially @Slem

Comment: @HASSAN: what was wrong or difficult to do in my suggestion?

Comment: @enzotib I try but it didn’t work. May I couldn't got what you actually said.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably messed up your `.bashrc` file and now you can't open a terminal anymore, because this file is used to set up your shell.

1. Boot into recovery mode. [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/88802)
2. Remount your system with write access:

   ```
   sudo mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
3. Copy the pristine `.bashrc` file from `/etc/skel` into your homedir to fix this. See [Where are the pristine, untouched contents of a ~/.profile file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/319207/88802) (also answers `.bashrc`), e.g.:

   ```
   cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~username/
   chown username: ~username/.bashrc
   ```

Comment: Why recovery? If he can login to the graphical session, why don't simply use a filemanager? And why to use `sudo` in recovery mode?  Also using `gnome-terminal -x bash --norc` is a simpler option than recovery mode.

Comment: @enzotib Will you still be able to log in to graphical session without proper `PATH` settings? I highly doubt that. So, unless he has another user on the system with sudo privileges (or plain root user activated), you'll have to use the recovery console. That's why. And thanks for the `sudo` in the commands in my answer, that's indeed not correct. fixed. :)

Comment: @enzotib Also, if you think you have a better alternative, write it as an answer. :)

Comment: I have a graphical session as well as am able to open the terminal.When I write "vi .bashrc"    its not work and show the following message. Command 'vi' is available in '/usr/bin/vi'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
vi: command not found
Can anyone answer me in a simple way??

Answer (score 0):

Could be the same problem: Try resetting your path with this command:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

([Source](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167454/basic-commands-in-unix-not-working-i-e-bash-ls-no-such-file-or-directory))

Comment: Please, could you add more details from the solution that you have found? Try to explain it with your words, it a sign of a thought answer.

Comment: I think the answer is very clear.  The error message says "/usr/bin is not included in the PATH environment variable" and this is "resetting the path".  Are you suggesting that a "thoughtful answer" would require an explanation of PATH?  Surely there is a balance between a "complete  answer" and one that is "direct and to the point"?