# No files in /etc/skel/ ; Can't restore .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bashrc, etc, skel

I recently messed up my .bashrc file, which I mentioned in this question: [How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/problem-with-installing-android-developer-files-on-eclipse-messed-up-something), and I can't find a way to restore .bashrc to its default that works.

I can't make commands in the terminal because every time I try I receive an error message along the lines of

> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH >environment variable.

On other questions I have seen that some recommendations for this problem involve using default files in /etc/skel/ ([Problem in .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319882/problem-in-bashrc?lq=1) ).

This won't work for me, as I looked in /etc/skel/, and realized that I have practically no files at all in there! I don't know why this is.

Also, solutions that involve using the terminal don't seem to work because every time I use the terminal I get the above-mentioned error message.

I'd be really appreciative if anybody could help me solve this problem. I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu, and I'm having difficulties with this issue.

Comment: Note -- I realized that the files in /etc/skel/ were hidden; I used ctrl + h and they are actually there. I copied the original .bashrc file to my home directory. However, the problem in the terminal still persists.

Comment: You will need to log out and back in or execute `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the default files in /etc/skel are hidden ('dot') files, so to see them in the GUI file manager you will need to `Show hidden files` from the menu or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> key combination.

To see them in a terminal you will need to use `ls -a` or `ls -A` i.e.

```
ls /etc/skel
examples.desktop
```

but

```
$ ls -A /etc/skel
.bash_logout  .bashrc  examples.desktop  .profile  .Xdefaults  .xscreensaver
```

Until you have fixed your path you will need to use the full path to each command e.g. `/bin/ls`,  `/bin/cp` e.g.

```
/bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_old
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

For the new .bashrc file to take effect, you will need to start a new shell or log out and back in - or you can *source* the new file in the shell using

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually .bashrc file on /etc/skel/ was hidden.Press ctrl+h to see the hidden .bashrc file.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this, and this info was a big help!